# I can not return an image file and show it in View using Ajax in Asp.net MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, image

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'image/jpeg',
                    url: '/Home/GetImage/' + img , 
                    success: function (data) {
                        i = new Image();
                        i.src = data;
                        $('#imageresult').append(i);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('error'); 
                    },
});


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetImage(string img)
{
   string imageFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Profile/Small/" );
   var path = Path.Combine(imageFile, img );  
   var srcImage = Image.FromFile(path);
   var stream = new MemoryStream();
   srcImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

   return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");
}
```

It always falls into  error function. If i remove dataType, then it doesn't fall into error function but it just shows long strings in the view. Why doesn't that work and show image in view?

Comment: you aren't sending any data then why POST?

Comment: Why aren't you using GET instead of POST? Agre, if you are using POST i think you need send some data.

Comment: ok i changed it as 'GET'

Comment: Try to send only `bytearray` then get the image in view. `return Json(stream.ToArray());`

Comment: I think the wrong here is on your attribute on controller is `HttpPost`,but your ajax call type is `GET`.One more thing why `dataType: 'image/jpeg'`,you are passing a string only

Comment: because i changed post to get attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something Like this:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string img)
{
   string imageFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Profile/Small/" );
   var path = Path.Combine(imageFile, img );  
   var srcImage = Image.FromFile(path);
   var stream = new MemoryStream();
   srcImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

   return Json(Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray()), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home")',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ItemPreview").attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        },
    });
```

and the view:

```
<img id="ItemPreview" src="" />
```

of course you can append `img` dynamically, then bind its source after.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the URL of an image with its actual content (the graphic bytes).

The `/GetImage` call returns the bytes, but you can never put data bytes in the `i.src` attribute because that attribute needs to be fed a URL.
It might work if you forget about the Ajax call and just use `i.src = '/Home/GetImage/' + img;`.